# Subscribe to multiple service call sequentially

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, mergemap

i have to do 2 api call, i want first call to complete and then the second call to start sequentially. 2nd call dont have any dependency on first call. both the call makes update to the DB.
if i use the below code, update to the second call is happening multiple times due to which it is trying update same record multiple time which i want avoid.any help is appreciated.

```
updateUserCommentsObservable(): Observable<any> {
  if (!this.userComments) {
    return EMPTY;
  }

  const source = this.arrayGroupBy<TrailerComparisonUserComment>(
    this.userComments, 
    comment => comment.trailerComparisonId);
  return from(Object.keys(source)).pipe(
    mergeMap(x => this.trailerComparisonService.updateUserComments(
      x, source[x])
    )
  );
}


this.updateUserCommentsObservable().pipe(
  flatMap(() => from(this.trailerComparisons).pipe(
    mergeMap(trailerComparison => 
      this.trailerComparisonService.saveReviewComplete(
        trailerComparison.trailerComparisonId))
    )
  )
).subscribe(() => {                   
  this.userComments = [];
  this.disableStage1Review = true;
  let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Well done! Stage1 Review Complete has been successfully saved.', 'Dismiss');                   
}, error => {                   
  console.log("Error", error);
  let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open('Error! ' + error.error.message, 'Dismiss');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple observables sequentially using the `concat` function.

```js
concat(
  obs1$,
  obs2$
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

If each observable returns 1 result and completes (an http request), then subscribe will receive 2 values - the result of `obs1$` and then the result of `obs2$`.

If you want to wait for both to return a result, you can use the `toArray` function.

```js
concat(
  obs1$,
  obs2$
).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The result in the subscribe will now be an array of `obs1$` result and `obs2$` result.

Your requirements are a bit more complex because you have an initial observable and then an array of observables. If you want to run your array of observables sequentially, then you can create the array of observables up front and pass them into concat.

```js
const trailerComparisons$ = this.trailerComparisons.map(c => 
  this.trailerComparisonService.saveReviewComplete(c.trailerComparisonId)
);

concat(
  this.updateUserCommentsObservable(),
  ...trailerComparisons$
).pipe(
  toArray()
).subscribe(/* subscribe handling */)
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jldrrh

Answer (score 0):

To make calls sequential you have to use `concatMap` instead of `mergeMap`.

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap